# Python Clarifai program stopped working inspite of no changes made

Tags: python, flask, grpc, clarifai

I have the following Python code to label images using Clarifai. It was a working code and had been usable for the past 6-8 months. However, for the last few days, I have been getting the error mentioned below. Note that I have not made any changes to the working version of the code for the error to creep in.

```
#python program to analyse an image and label it

'''
Dependencies:
pip install flask
pip install clarifai-grpc
pip install logging
'''

import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 
import logging
import os

from clarifai_grpc.channel.clarifai_channel import ClarifaiChannel
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api import resources_pb2, service_pb2, service_pb2_grpc
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api.status import status_pb2, status_code_pb2

channel = ClarifaiChannel.get_json_channel()

stub = service_pb2_grpc.V2Stub(channel)

# This will be used by every Clarifai endpoint call.
# The word 'Key' is required to precede the authentication key.
metadata = (('authorization', 'Key API_KEY_HERE'),)

webapp = Flask(__name__) #creating a web application for the current python file

#decorators
@webapp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', len=0)
  
@webapp.route('/' , methods = ['POST'])

def search():

    if request.form['searchByURL']:

        url = request.form['searchByURL']

        my_request = service_pb2.PostModelOutputsRequest(
            # This is the model ID of a publicly available General model.
            #You may use any other public or custom model ID.
            model_id='aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c',
            inputs=[
              resources_pb2.Input(data=resources_pb2.Data(image=resources_pb2.Image(url=url)))
            ])
        response = stub.PostModelOutputs(my_request, metadata=metadata)

        if response.status.code != status_code_pb2.SUCCESS:
            message = ["You have reached the limit for today!"]
            return render_template('/index.html' , len = 1, searchResults = message) 
            

        concepts = []

        
        for concept in response.outputs[0].data.concepts:
            concepts.append(concept.name)

        concepts = concepts[0:10]
        return render_template('/index.html' , len = len(concepts), searchResults = concepts )



    elif request.files['searchByImage']:

        file = request.files['searchByImage']    
        file.save(file.filename)

        #IMAGE INPUT:
        with open(file.filename, "rb") as f:
            file_bytes = f.read()

        post_model_outputs_response = stub.PostModelOutputs(
            service_pb2.PostModelOutputsRequest(
                model_id="aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c",
                version_id="aa7f35c01e0642fda5cf400f543e7c40",  # This is optional. Defaults to the latest model version.
                inputs=[
                    resources_pb2.Input(
                        data=resources_pb2.Data(
                            image=resources_pb2.Image(
                                base64=file_bytes
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ]
            ),
            metadata=metadata
        )
        
        if post_model_outputs_response.status.code != status_code_pb2.SUCCESS:
            message = ["You have reached the limit for today!"]
            return render_template('/index.html' , len = 1, searchResults = message)

        # Since we have one input, one output will exist here.
        output = post_model_outputs_response.outputs[0]
        os.remove(file.filename)
        concepts = []
        #Predicted concepts:
        for concept in output.data.concepts:
            concepts.append(concept.name)           
  
        concepts = concepts[0:10]


        return render_template('/index.html' , len = len(concepts), searchResults = concepts )

    else:
        return render_template('/index.html' , len = 1, searchResults = ["No Image entered!"] )

#run the server
if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'error.log' , level = logging.DEBUG, )
    webapp.run(debug=True)
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
  File "/Users/eshaangupta/Desktop/Python-Level-4/Image Analyser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from clarifai_grpc.channel.clarifai_channel import ClarifaiChannel
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run this on a different architecture than you've been in the past.  You've been running on x86 (looks like likely MacOS) and now have moved to an arm architecture.  I'm guessing you've upgraded to an M1 chip macbook, although maybe you've moved over to a different ARM based chip.

`(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))`

This is a problem with a file in grpc - specifically the library file `cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so`.  I'd recommend removing gRPC and re-installing and see if that helps to resolve it.

Something like this might work:

```
python -m pip install --force-reinstall grpcio
```

(This is assuming python points to python3.10 in your system).

although I'm not sure how you've installed it so that is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes you are right, I did shift to M1 Mac. I tried the above solution but it did not work. How to I ensure that python points to 3.10 in my system?

Comment: You can run `python --version` to check - it probably does since I assume you're getting that error when you run something with just python.

Comment: You can also try `python3.10 -m pip install --force-reinstall grpcio` instead which will force it.  If that doesn't work `python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall grpcio` might.  You can also just uninstall grpcio with pip and then re-install it instead of trying the --force-reinstall.

Comment: @EshaanGupta any luck with it?

Comment: No sorry, I tried the solution but it didn't seem to work